# Color different when I save a svg image

Tags: svg, adobe-illustrator

In my .ai (illustrator) file you can see the right color:

[image]

But when I save to web SVG the colors change to more lighter colors:
[image]

What is happening?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a programming question so off-topic. Perhaps try http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ (check their help centre first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think illustrators svg export functionality includes blend mode filtering. So all of your blends are not being rendered, just the basic shape fill colors. I believe you could achieve your blend effects with filters or css, but it would likely have to be done outside of illustrator in the svg or web code.